# HttpClient in using statement causes Task cancelled

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library, httpclient, using-statement

I created a `FileResult : IHttpActionResult` webapi return type for my api calls. The FileResult downloads a file from another url and then returns the stream to the client.

Initially my code had a `using` statement like below:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {

            response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(
                                    await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(this.filePath))
            };
        }
        return response;
    }
    catch (WebException exception)
    {...}
}
```

However this would intermittently cause a `TaskCanceledException`. I know that if the HttpClient is disposed before the asychronous call is finished the Task's state will change to canceled. However since I use an **await** in: `Content = new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(this.filePath))` that should prevent the HttpClient from being disposed off in the middle of the task completion.

**Why does that task get canceled?** It is not because of a timeout since this has happened on the smallest requests and doesn't always occur on large requests.

When I removed the `using` statement the code worked properly:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(
                                await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(this.filePath))
        };
        return response;
    }
    catch (WebException exception)
    {...}
}
```

Any idea why the using caused the issue?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Checking it step by step.

Comment: Yes I have. It doesn't really help since the exception isn't thrown here but in a completely different location. It occurs in the Owin pipeline I'm using where authentication is and it awaits the next request.

Comment: Does the `TaskCanceledException` have any inner exception?

Comment: There is no inner exception.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I know that if the HttpClient is disposed before the asychronous call is finished the Task's state will change to canceled. However since I use an await in: Content = new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(this.filePath)) that should prevent the HttpClient from being disposed off in the middle of the task completion.

But what does that task *do?* It gets the stream. So, your code ends up with a `Stream` that may or may not be completely read when it closes the `HttpClient`.

`HttpClient` is specifically designed for reuse (and simultaneous use), so I recommend removing the `using` completely and moving the `HttpClient` declaration to a `static` class member. But if you want to close and reopen the clients, you should be able to get it working by *reading* the stream entirely into memory before closing the `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with Task Canceled exceptions. If you try catching `AggregateException` or having a catch all `Exception` block underneath your `WebException`, you may well find that you catch it, with one exception with the entry stating "A task was canceled"

I did some investigation and found that the `AggregateException` is quite misleading as described in various threads;

[Setting HttpClient to a too short timeout crashes process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363536/setting-httpclient-to-a-too-short-timeout-crashes-process)

[How can I tell when HttpClient has timed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547895/how-can-i-tell-when-httpclient-has-timed-out)

[Bug in httpclientgetasync should throw webexception not taskcanceledexception](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8d87789-0ac9-4294-84a0-91c9fa27e353/bug-in-httpclientgetasync-should-throw-webexception-not-taskcanceledexception?forum=netfxnetcom&prof=required)

I ended up changing my code to set an explicit timeout (where `asyncTimeoutInMins` is read from the app.config file);

```
        string jsonResponse = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.MyWebService);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, asyncTimeoutInMins, 0);

                HttpResponseMessage response;

                response = await httpClient.GetAsync("/myservice/resource");

                // Check the response StatusCode
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Read the content of the response into a string
                    jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                {
                    jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    Logger.Instance.Warning(new HttpRequestException(string.Format("The response StatusCode was {0} - {1}", response.StatusCode.ToString(), jsonResponse)));

                    Environment.Exit((int)ExitCodes.Unauthorised);
                }
                else
                {
                    jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    Logger.Instance.Warning(new HttpRequestException(string.Format("The response StatusCode was {0} - {1}", response.StatusCode.ToString(), jsonResponse)));

                    Environment.Exit((int)ExitCodes.ApplicationError);
                }
           }

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException reqEx)
        {
            Logger.Instance.Error(reqEx);

            Console.WriteLine("HttpRequestException : {0}", reqEx.InnerException.Message);

            Environment.Exit((int)ExitCodes.ApplicationError);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Instance.Error(ex);

            throw;
        }

        return jsonResponse;
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above the exception isn't caught there but in authentication logic layer.